babel.config.js not initially being created when running expo but crashes when manually created
When I run npx create-expo-app@latest ./ the babel.config.js file is not being created and since I want to be running nativewind I would need to modify the babel.config.js file. First I run npx expo customize and select the babel.config.js file but it won't get created in my root folder, the terminal tells me exiting with no change... and it doesn't appear anywhere in my project. Then I tried not having to use babel.config.js but at some point I had to create it. Before creating the file Expo Go on my phone would run no problem, but when I create the babel.config.js file it crashes the app and won't work anymore.
Could someone please help me because I am stuck and haven't been able to find a solution. Thank you

After running expo customize and highlighting the babel config file use the right arrow key to select it before clicking enter.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
